# How to solve app manifest error in WinUI 3 - "The file name doesn't exist in the package"

Tags: winui, appxmanifest

I'm trying to publish a packaged app to the Windows Store using the `pack` and `publish` option and I'm getting failure with this info:

```
The file name "AudioChapterEditor.exe" declared for element
"*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']"
doesn't exist in the package.
```

My app is called **Audio Chapter Editor**, and the solution is titled **AudioChapterEditor**. The `appxmanifest` is here, where I assume it's having the problem. (Minor edits for privacy maybe? Not sure what's private in this file!)

The rescap line at the bottom is highlighted in Visual Studio with a warning about being unknown, but it's what the documentation says should be in a WinUI 3 project, and I think it's what was created when I made the project in VS... it seems this kind of error comes up for others when bundling things, particularly executable files, into the application, but my app doesn't need or have that.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity
    Name="xxxxxNatex.AudioChapterEditor"
    Publisher="CN=XXXXXXXX-F522-4723-8422-EB217E3E071F"
    Version="1.0.2.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="XXXXXXXX-39f8-4588-a25d-d72b56c6b2c0" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Audio Chapter Editor</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Nate x</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\Square150x150Logo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="Audio Chapter Editor"
        Description="A tool that enables easy and stylish editing of audio chapter files in Windows 11. Designed for podcasters."
        BackgroundColor="transparent"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Resources\BarCafeChair.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

EDIT: See below. This isn't fixed or solved, but it is only happening from trying to package the x86 app. Huh.

Comment: So, for whatever reason, this is only occurring when I generate an X86 package. If I don't build for X86, I don't get the error. I asked about it on the GitHub page too and didn't get an answer, so I'll post this finding there as well. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/8398